# How to color specific characters in an Arabic string?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

In Arabic languages, specific characters are colored as a rule. How can I color those characters. 
I tried coloring it using Spannable string. But the sentence gets distorted.

Here is the image to show what I meant by distorted.

[image: Distort text]

There is an app (Iquran) is available on play google which implements this functionality.

[image]

So what's the best way to implement this functionality?

Comment: Please blur English content

Comment: @waqar any luck sir? I am doing a similar task, please guide if you found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to implement this is using html.

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<i><small><font color=\"#c5c5c5\">" + "Competitor ID: " + "</font></small></i>" + "<font color=\"#47a842\">" + compID + "</font>"));
```

you can use

```
String.replace("ARABICCHAR","</font></small></i>ARABICCHAR<font color=\"#c5c5c5\">"
```

and then just use textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(String));

Comment: The text still gets distorted. I tried this before.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could easily accomplish this is using a custom font where those specific letters are specific colours. Then just use your custom font.